# Display category entries based on Segment?

Tags: categories

I'm really struggling to display entries of a category, based on the segment. In other words, I have 1 category template, so the category needs to be determined dynamically (*we still  do this by segment, right?? or is that not the best practice?)

I was trying something like this, but I can't seem to get it right:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('typeOfPack').find() %}
     {% set active = (
        craft.request.Segment(2) == category.slug
     ) %}

    {% for entry in entry.typeOfPack.search('active').find()  %}
        <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}


{% endfor %}
```

Apologies if this offensively bad. As I try to get my head around Twig, I'm wondering if there are some high level errors, for instance: 
1. Does the {% for entry... %} need to be inside the {%for category... %}? Do I even need to do the {% for category...%} stuff if I'm just needing entries, or is the ".search(...)" sufficient?

Thank you so much.

Big Mike

Answer (score 2):

[How do I list the entries related to a category?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entries-related-to-category) article on the Craft site should get you headed in the right direction.

> You can fetch the entries related to a given category with a little
>   help from [craft.entries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) and the [relatedTo](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) param.

```
{# Fetch all of the entries related to this category #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}

{# Output them #}
{% for entry in entries %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```